# Клавиатура VK API, PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

не могу разобраться с клавиатурой ВК. [Документация ВК](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20JSON%3A)
Как её реализовать? Искал в сети примеры/объяснения так не нашёл для PHP.

```
switch($user_msg){
//=======================================================
    case "Скинь котика":

        $file = file_get_contents($config['album_1'], LOCK_EX);
        $photos_all = explode("\n", $file);
        $mp->photoSend($photos_all[mt_rand(0, count($photos_all) - 1)], $user_id, $access_token);
            break;
//=======================================================
    case "Скинь рыбку":

        $file = file_get_contents($config['album_2'], LOCK_EX);
        $photos_all = explode("\n", $file);
        $mp->photoSend($photos_all[mt_rand(0, count($photos_all) - 1)], $user_id, $access_token);
            break;
//=======================================================
    case "Скинь собачку":

        $file = file_get_contents($config['album_3'], LOCK_EX);
        $photos_all = explode("\n", $file);
        $mp->photoSend($photos_all[mt_rand(0, count($photos_all) - 1)], $user_id, $access_token);
            break;
//=======================================================
    case "Скинь птичку":

        $file = file_get_contents($config['album_4'], LOCK_EX);
        $photos_all = explode("\n", $file);
        $mp->photoSend($photos_all[mt_rand(0, count($photos_all) - 1)], $user_id, $access_token);
            break;
}
```

Как добавить в данный код клавиатуру (что бы у пользователя появилось 4 варианта (команды) при нажатии на который отправлял бы соответствующее изображение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорится "Хочешь сделать хорошо, сделай это сам"… Вот как я реализовал клавиатуру для бота в ВК. API 5.92

---

```
class message_keyboard{  
    public function send($msg, $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token){ 
        $request_params = array(
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            "random_id" => "0",
            "message" => $msg,
            "keyboard" => json_encode($keyboard, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
            "access_token" => $access_token,
            "v" => "5.92");
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?".$get_params);}}
```

---

```
$mk = new message_keyboard();

switch($data->type){
    case "confirmation":
        echo $confirmation_token;
        break;
        
    case "message_new":
        
        switch($message){
            case "Овощи?":
                $keyboard = [
                    "one_time" => false,
                    "buttons" => [[
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "payload" => '{"button": "1"}',
                    "label" => "Фрукты?"],
                    "color" => "default"],
                ]]];
                
$mk->send("Картоха", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);
                break;
                
            case "Фрукты?":
                $keyboard = [
                    "one_time" => false,
                    "buttons" => [[
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "payload" => '{"button": "1"}',
                    "label" => "Овощи?"],
                    "color" => "default"],
                ]]];
                
$mk->send("ЯблОчко =)", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);
                break;
}
```

Comment: Ты лучший, я весь инет перерыл, спасибо тебе)))